# No serial data received: ESP32 CAM

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I keep getting error as I upload my code to my AI thinker esp 32 cam. I connect it using microusb and it always has this error:

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution until I came about [this post](https://community.platformio.org/t/espcam-vscode-failed-to-connect-esp32-no-serial-data-received/30224/3) that suggests to perform the following steps:

- Plug the board in (i.e. connect it to your computer via a USB cable)
- Press **and hold** the `IO0` (which is on the board with the USB connector)
- Now press the `RST` button (this one is on the ESP32-CAM board, slightly tricky to press when the two boards are plugged together, but possible)
- Release both buttons

Now the `ESP32-CAM` should be in bootloader mode and you should be able to upload sketches to it.

Comment: Bravo, finally I could upload a sketch!! Note that there is also a RST on the dev board, this one is not the one that the Grogsenegger points to, he points to the one just behind the sd card slot!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All the suggestions did not fix my problem.
However, I downloaded a usb to serial driver and installed it before i tried to upload again, and it succeeded. The problem is gone.

See [the CH340 Drivers page](https://sparks.gogo.co.nz/ch340.html)